# FB API GRAPH get not upcoming events

Tags: javascript, facebook-javascript-sdk

i use FB Api graph on JS SDK, but i have a problem.
I have not access at upcoming events but just event passed.

with {page_id}/events

```
FB.api(
'/{page_id}/events',
'GET',
{'access_token':'{token}'},
function(response) {
});
```

Do you have any solution ?

Comment: Have you tried the `time_filter` parameter ...? https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/page/events#parameters

Comment: Nice thanks you so much